# SetValue in beforerender listener not updating anything

Tags: extjs, listener, setvalue

I'm using ExtJS and I'm having a hard time setting a value in a *combofield*.

In a **before render** event I'm trying to set the value of the combobox by using the provided method **setValue**. However, there is no change.

```
 beforerender : function(field) {
                          field.setValue(2018);
                          console.log("I'm here !");

              },
```

I'll give the list of things thatI've already tried :

1. set the value as a string instead of a number (= 2018+"")
2. use **setVisible()** after setting the value (this works but the layout is messed up)
3. setting the value manually by using the correct attribute (= field.value =2018)
4. using another event such as focus (note that for this event the **setValue** method does work)

I'd like to add that there is another component inheriting from this component, which could potentially cause a reference issue.

Is it possible to use the **setValue** in a **before render** event ?

Comment: Have you tried `field.value = 2018` in the `beforerender`?

Answer (score 0):

Your piece of code seems alright, your combobox has data in its store when the beforerender listener is called? Remember that when you call `setValue()` on combobox:

> For each value, if a record is found in the store that matches based on the valueField, then that record's displayField will be displayed in the field

So, if in your combobox's config, your valueField is set to `valueField:year`, and you call `setValue(2018)`, the combobox will look in its store and look for a record like `{year:2018}`

Example :

```
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
  data: [{
    "abbr": "AL",
    "name": "Alabama"
  }, {
    "abbr": "AK",
    "name": "Alaska"
  }, {
    "abbr": "AZ",
    "name": "Arizona"
  }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
  fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
  store: states,
  queryMode: 'local',
  displayField: 'name',
  valueField: 'abbr',
  listeners:{
    beforerender:function(cmp){
      cmp.setValue('AK');
    }
  },
  renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: The valueField is written as you mentionned. However, there isn't anything being changed. I also tried to set the value of other combobox in the fieldset but no success either. Finally, if I print the combo in the console and then I set the value in the console, the value is updated. Why is that ?

Comment: Its kinda hard to know why this is happening without all your code, can you make a fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/ ?